# Laravel 5/AngularJS custom authentication best practice

Tags: angularjs, authentication, laravel-5

I'm working on an application using Laravel 5.3 as a back end and AngularJS as the front end. For authentication, the user's information needs to be matched against an external API. To do so, I've been using a custom version of Laravel's built-in authentication, i.e.,

1. User enters information
2. AngularJS front-end sends to Laravel back-end
3. Laravel uses Auth::login to check against external API
4. Either tell the user that their credentials are wrong or move them to the home page

My question is, from that point forward, is it bad practice to continue using Laravel's built-in auth middleware functionality to see if the user is authenticated when they move around the application?

Everything I'm reading seems to discuss using token based authentication (mostly JWT), and while my method definitely works, I'm new to AngularJS and would like to ensure that what I'm doing follows best practice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as best practices go there are a lot of different ways to go about it. You could use laravel's built in Authentication but you'd have to make sure that the session id keeps getting sent with every request or Auth::user will be null.

When it comes to API's you usually dont want to have session data though, the main reason people use tokens like JWT or OAUTH is because they're stateless (for the most part). If you use JWT tokens then you could add an extra middelware with something like this:

```
if (JWTAuth::getToken()) {
        JWTAUth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    }
```

When you do something like this then laravel's authentication methods will work as expected. This would be in combination with jwt.auth middleware which comes with the package. Hope that clears things up a little :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I think I understand what you're saying, although I'm still a bit fuzzy on the implementation. Any chance you have any thoughts on using Laravel's Passport package?

Comment: Implementation with this method would just to make sure the middleware I described is used before any laravel standard auth middleware.

I have never used Laravel's Passport package but from what I read in the docs its also a token based service like JWT. It's probably be even easier to implement since it comes from laravel itself. I would follow the docs [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) and you should get to where you want with authentication :)